# How to skip the parent tag, based on the value of a child tag in XML Parsing using SAX Parser

Tags: java, sax, saxparser

```
<root>
<parent>
    <child1> 30</child1>
    <child2> 30</child2>
    <child3> 30</child3>
</parent>
 <parent>
    <child1> 20</child1>
    <child2> 30</child2>
    <child3> 30</child3>
</parent>
 <parent>
    <child1> 30</child1>
    <child2> 30</child2>
    <child3> 30</child3>
</parent>
</root>
```

I am really new to the world of coding and to sax parsing.. 
Consider the above XML, what I need is. .. based on the value of the tag child1, if it is greater than 20, only then I would want to parse the remaining child tags(child2 and child3), otherwise I would want to move on to the next parent tag.

Could anyone pls suggest what would be the ideal way to do it?

Comment: Why sax only?is it for huge XML?

Comment: Yes it is for huge xml , and also it is an already existing code, I am trying to do some modifications.

Comment: how huge is huge? 100s of mb or 100 of gb?

Comment: Not 'GB' huge. It is less than a hundered MB. Do you suggest any other parser instead of SAX in such a case, which would help me with the above situation?

Comment: Okay thank you. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
...
private boolean skipChildren;
private StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
...

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equals("parent")) {
        skipChildren = false;
        ...
    } else if (qName.equals("child1")) {
        buf.setLength(0);
        ...
    } else if (qName.startsWith("child")) {
        if (!skipChildren) {
            buf.setLength(0);
            ...
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equals("parent")) {
        ...
    } else if (qName.equals("child1")) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(buf.toString().trim());
        if (value <= 20) {
            skipChildren = true;
        }
        ...
    } else if (qName.startsWith("child")) {
        if (!skipChildren) {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(buf.toString().trim());
            doSomethingWith(value);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
    if (!skipChildren) {
        buf.append(ch, start, length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Maurice Perry. Looks like this would work.

Comment: so many thanks for your reply but shouldn't it be if(skipChildren) in startElement function? @Maurice Perry

Comment: @RezaNamvar no: you want to skip the children if `skipChildren` is true, not process them.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to perform your task with [vtd-xml](http://vtd-xml.sf.net), it is the state of art in xml processing technology, and is a lot more efficient and simpler to write than SAX... the key is by using xpath expression to filter out only the nodes of interest... read [this paper](http://sdiwc.us/digitlib/journal_paper.php?paper=00000582.pdf) that gives you loads of reasons to avoid SAX parsing whenever possible

[Processing XML with Java – A Performance Benchmark](http://sdiwc.us/digitlib/journal_paper.php?paper=00000582.pdf)

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
public class conditionalSelection {
    public static void main(String s[]) throws VTDException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if(!vg.parseFile("d:\\xml\\condition.xml", false)) // disable namespace
            return;
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/root/parent[child1>20]"); // the xpath selecting all parents with child1>20
        int i=0,j=0;
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            // now move the cursor to child2 and child3
            if(vn.toElement(VTDNav.FC,"child2")){
                j = vn.getText();
                if (j!=-1)//make sure the text node exist
                    System.out.println(" child2's text node is ==>"+ vn.toString(j));
                vn.toElement(VTDNav.P);
            }
            if(vn.toElement(VTDNav.FC,"child3")){
                j = vn.getText();
                if (j!=-1)//make sure the text node exist
                    System.out.println(" child3's text node is ==>"+ vn.toString(j));
                vn.toElement(VTDNav.P);
            }
        }
    }
```